# How do I write a member function that returns a type that only exists in the class?

Tags: c++, list

I'm actually implementing a doubly-linked list in C++.

Here's a MWE of sorts:

```
namespace mynamespace {

template <typename T>
class List {
public:
    List();

    void prepend(T);
    void append(T);
    void remove(T);

private:
    struct Node {
        T value_;
        Node * prev_;
        Node * next_;
    };

private:
    Node * find(T); // <-- THIS IS MY PROBLEM

private:
    Node * head_;
    Node * tail_;
};

}
```

The reason I'd like to create that function is because I figured it'd be handy if I could traverse the list with a function like that until I find a given element (I'll need to do the same with the `remove()` function anyways)

*But how do I define that function outside the `class` definition?*

Since `Node` is a private member of the `List` class, this is not working:

```
template <typename T>
Node * List<T>::find(T val)
{
    // stuff
}
```

I suppose defining the function *inside* the `class` definition would work, because `Node` makes sense there... Would that be the proper way? Even if so, I suppose there must be a way to define the function the way I'm trying to...

Comment: Just like you have to do `List<T>::find` to tell the compiler where `find` is you need to do the same thing to `Node`.

Comment: @Justin thanks, that works! I was missing the `typename` (I tried what you and @NathanOliver initally said, but I thought that was wrong too, because w/o the `typename`, I got errors). Would you please add this as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution? Also, would you explain why I need the `typename`?

Comment: Note that in templates, I generally tend to use `const T&` arguments rather than `T`, so in case `T` is something like `std::string` there won't be an unnecessary copy.  (A possible exception would be "insert" type operations like your `prepend` or `append` where you can use a pass-by-value and then *move* the parameter into the container, in order to avoid having to write separate copy `prepend(const T&)` and move `prepend(T&&)` versions of the method.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Since `Node` is a private member of the `List` class, this is not working:

Actually, that's not correct. It's not failing because `Node` is private, but because `Node` is nested inside of `List`. The name of the `Node` class isn't `Node`, it's `List<T>::Node`. However, since `Node` [depends on `T`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), you have to write `typename List<T>::Node`, otherwise the compiler assumes that `List<T>::Node` is a value rather than a type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1896169) for more information.

In short, replace this:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> Node * List<T>::find(T val)
> ```

With this:

```
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node * List<T>::find(T val)
```

---

Alternatively, as StoryTeller noted, if you are in the context of the `List<T>` class, you can just use `Node`. You can get in this context by using a trailing return type:

```
template <typename T>
auto List<T>::find(T val) -> Node *
```

Comment: Or `auto List<T>::find(T) -> Node*`. I find it less painful on the eyes myself.