# Using a type alias inside a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, type-alias

I have class template that I want to make, and the only template parameter `n` will be used to make a `std::array<double,n>` data member. However, this is tricky to do when I am using type aliases. It seems that type aliases aren't recognized when you're trying to write down the return type of a class method. What is the best workaround for this?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t n> class C {

    using arr = std::array<double,n>;

public:
    C();
    arr func(); 
};


template<size_t n> 
C<n>::C() {}


template<size_t n> 
arr C<n>::func() { // <--------------------right here
    arr temp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        temp[i] = i;
    return temp; 
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C<10> obj; 
}
```

Comment: Your alias is not `public`, that will solve your issue

Comment: @CoryKramer if I make it public, it still won't fix it

Comment: If you make it public you still have to access it properly, i.e. make the return type `typename C<n>::arr`.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49678585/1896169

Comment: In your example, the correct type of the alias is `C<n>::arr`, not that it is also in the `C` class namespace

Comment: @Justin - I was trying to find that one before answering :)